# Displaying PHP results?

Tags: php, mysql, html

I need a little help here with some php.
just a little explanation:
(im trying to display 5 results using this code

```
    $n_id = mysql_real_escape_string ($_GET['id']);
    $path = '';

    if(isset($n_id) && $n_id != "") {
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM test2 WHERE id="' . $n_id . '"';
        $news = mysql_query($sql);

    if($result = mysql_fetch_array($news)) {
        $title = mysql_result($news,0,"title");
        $date = mysql_result($news,0,"date");
        echo '<b>' . $title . ' | ' . $date . '</b>
        <br/>
        <img src="images.php?id='. $n_id .'>';
    } else {
        header("Location: vendi.php");
    }
    echo '<br /><a href="/'.$path.'">Back to Archive</a>';
    }
```

It does display but i want that 1st result to be (image+title of the news and other results to be just title).
Hope i wrote it clearly what i needed help with. 
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL statement is only fetching a single row. This isn't a complete solution, but should get you closer:

```
if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id'])) {
    $n_id = (int)$_GET['id'];
    $path = '';

    $count = 0;

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM test2 WHERE id BETWEEN ' . $n_id ' AND ' . ($n_id + 5);
    $news = mysql_query($sql);

    while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($news)) {
        $title = $result['title'];
        $date = $result['date'];
        echo '<b>' . $title . ' | ' . $date . '</b>';
        if ($count < 1) {
            echo '<br/><img src="images.php?id='. $n_id .'>';
            $count++;
        }
    }

    if ($count == 0) { header("Location: vendi.php"); }

    echo '<br /><a href="/'.$path.'">Back to Archive</a>';
}
```

Comment: THANKS YOUR ANSWER HELPED VERY MUCH TO DO THE JOB i modified my self but you were the head start thnx

Answer (score 0):

While looping through your results, you can check if you are at the first result:

```
$counter = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($news)) {
    $title = mysql_result($news,0,"title");
    $date = mysql_result($news,0,"date");
    echo '<b>' . $title . ' | ' . $date . '</b>';
    if ( $counter == 0 ) {
        echo '<br /><img src="images.php?id='. $n_id .'>';
    }

}
```

Comment: You're missing a close to your echo.
I think he's going to have to switch up the SQL call too.  Looks like he's doing a single row atm.  That could get tetchier without more info.

Comment: You're assigning a value here: `if ( $counter = 0 ) {`  Should be `==`

Comment: Fixed, and fixed. Thanks. As to the single row issue, he said he is trying to display five results.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
$n_id = mysql_real_escape_string ($_GET['id']);
    $path = '';

    if(isset($n_id) && $n_id != "") {
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM test2 WHERE id="' . $n_id . '"';
        $news = mysql_query($sql);

        $first = TRUE;
        if($result = mysql_fetch_array($news)) {
            $title = mysql_result($news,0,"title");
            $date = mysql_result($news,0,"date");

            if($first == TRUE) {
                echo '<b>' . $title . ' | ' . $date . '</b>';
                $first = FALSE;
            }
            else {
                echo '<b>' . $title . ' | ' . $date . '</b>
                <br/>
                <img src="images.php?id='. $n_id .'>';
            }
        }
        else {
            header("Location: vendi.php");
        }
        echo '<br /><a href="/'.$path.'">Back to Archive</a>';
        }
    }
```